# Having a problem using useEffect to fetch data in react native since changing from a class to function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, use-effect

I am having a problem using the useEffect method to fetch data on load and then to watch for changes in a state.

I am not sure if it loading the data at all or I am using the fetch correctly as I am simply trying to alert the data which I know it will not do correctly because it is an array but it basically does not even call the alert but the code worked in class, this is a functional component.

Any ideas where I am going wrong? Thanks and the code is below and I am not asking anyone to do this, just point me out where I am going wrong as I am very to RN:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';

import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const loadusers = async () =>{
    try{
      let data = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20&nat=us", {method: 'GET'});
      let json = await data.json();
      setUsers(json); 
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log("Im catching the error");
      console.log(err);
      setUsers([]);
    } 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
   loadusers();
  },[])

   useEffect(() => {
     //alert(users) 
  },[users])

    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <List>
                {users.map((user, i) => (
                    <ListItem
                        roundAvatar
                        avatar={{ uri: user.picture.thumbnail }}
                        key={i}
                        title={user.name.first + " " + user.name.last}
                    />
                ))}
            </List>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
})
```

Comment: You can tell if it’s loading the users via a breakpoint or a log.

Comment: I am  using expo online